# Identically Distributed Casella and Berger

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was  reading Statistical Inference in Casella and Berger and saw that they define $X$ and $Y$ identically distributed if $\forall\mathbb{B}\in\mathbb{R}$

$$P(Y\in B)=P(X\in B)$$

It is my understanding that identically distributed does not require random variables to be defined on the same space that is $X$ and $Y$ can be defined on different probability triples. It appears to me that in this definition they are defining the random variables on the same probability triple given the same measure $P$. The only way I can see this happening for r.v defined on different spaces is constructing the product space on the two different probability triples and $P$ is the new measure defined on this space. I guess I am just confused on whether $P$ is the probability measure or its just sloppy notation to signify probability on whatever $X$ and $Y$ are defined on. Can someone help clarify my confusion?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528250/do-two-random-variables-defined-on-different-probability-spaces-have-the-same-di

Answer (score 2):

The probability $P$ you have here is not the measure in your probability triples. You have some "black box" set $\Omega$ with its $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{T}$ and its probability measure $\mathbb{P}$, but when you describe the law of your random variable $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ you use the induced measure $P$ defined by $P(B)=\mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(B))$. Thus you r.v. $Y:\Omega'\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can be defined on another triplet, its law will still be expressed with an induced measure on $\mathbb{R}$ which will be the same as $X$. You are still right on one thing:  it is not supposed to be the "same" $P$ in both $P(X\in B)$ and $P(Y\in B)$, but one often allow such abuse since you **can** construct a greater probability triplet including both of your variables without changing the law of your variables nor the way they behave as a couple.

Comment: By greater probability triple are you referring to the construction of a product space and can define the prob of X=x by taking the whole space of Y and the Cartesian product with x which produces the same prob as On the original Space of X